# Scout SDk usage in command line

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-scout

Is there any possibility to use Scout SDK from command line? 
E.g. Is it possible to create new Scout project and forms, pages, etc using command line or some tool which can do that ?

I'm using scout in Eclipse IDE now and I'd like to use common things (done via Eclipse IDE) via command line.

Comment: What do the docs say?

Answer (score 1):

this [discussion](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781488/) is currently led in the scout forum @ eclipse. we probably should try to open a topic for the scout framework on stackoverflow ...